# Can I setup two-factor authentication for mobile only

Tags: authentication

We have everything we need as far as authentication using a third party application.

BUT if I relax IP restrictions for mobile, am I able to set up two-factor authentication through Salesforce **only** for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation on How to set up Two Factor Authentication for Android and iOs Devices [Set Up Two Factor Authentication for mobile (Android/iOs)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000341505&type=1&mode=1)

**Steps to set up Two Factor Authentication for the mobile app Users**

**Steps in Lightning Experience:**

1. Navigate to Setup | Apps | Connected Apps | Manage Connected Apps |
   Salesforce for iOS.
2. Click Edit.
3. In the 'OAuth Policies' section, set the IP Relaxation setting to
   Relax IP restrictions with second factor.
4. In the 'Session Policies' section, click the High assurance session
   required checkbox.
5. Click Save.

Note: You will need to repeat these steps in Salesforce for Android as well.